# Use modulus in for loops in deeper levels with specific structures

Tags: php, for-loop, operators, modulus

I'm trying to loop through some images I have named in a folder using php. The problem here is that I need to place the images in an specific markup because I will use them dynamically in a carousel.

Normally I just loop through the items:

```
<div class="slider">
<?php
  for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    if ($x == 0) {
      echo '<div class="slide active"><img src="img_'.$x.'"></div>';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="slide"><img src="img_'.$x.'"></div>';
    }
  }
?>
</div>
```

I tried to add four images to each slide, using modulus to count and add markup between them:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide active">
  <?php
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
      if ($x % 4 == 0) {
        echo '<img src="img_'.$x.'"></div><div class="slide">';
      } else {
        echo '<img src="img_'.$x.'">';
      }
    }
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the slider work with a specific structure where the images are nested in different divs, like this:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide active">
  <!-- -->
    <div class="slider-container">
      <div class="flexChild rowParent">
        <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_0.jpg"></div>
        <div class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_1.jpg"></div>
          <div class="flexChild rowParent">
            <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_3.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
  <!-- -->
    <div class="slider-container">
      <div class="flexChild rowParent">
        <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_4.jpg"></div>
        <div class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_5.jpg"></div>
          <div class="flexChild rowParent">
            <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_6.jpg"></div>
            <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_7.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
  <!-- -->
    <div class="slider-container">
      <div class="flexChild rowParent">
        <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_8.jpg"></div>
        <div class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_9.jpg"></div>
          <div class="flexChild rowParent">
            <div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_10.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to loop through these items with this structure, but I have not succeeded. If you have any suggestions on how can this be done, I would really appreciate it! I have looked all over for this, but I couldn't find any result. Is it posible to achieve, or should I just drop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the structure you want, we need to use two loops:

```
<?php
    $result = '';
    $x = 0;
    $items = 10;
    while($x <= $items){
        if($x == 0){
            $result .= '<div class="slider"><div class="slide active"> <!-- --> <div class="slider-container"><div class="flexChild rowParent">';
        }else{
            $result .= '<div class="slider"><div class="slide"> <!-- --> <div class="slider-container"><div class="flexChild rowParent">';
        }           

        $result .= '<div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_'.$x.'.jpg"></div>';
        $result .= '<div class="flexChild columnParent">';

        $result .= '<div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_'.($x+1).'.jpg"></div>';
        $result .= '<div class="flexChild rowParent">';

        for($y=2; $y<=3; $y++){
            if(($x + $y) <= $items){
                $result .= '<div class="flexChild flex-element"><img src="img_'.($x+$y).'.jpg"></div>';
            }
        }

        $result .= '</div></div></div></div><!-- --></div></div>';
        $x += 4;
    }

    echo $result;
?>
```